# how to to extract all text of the form "<key>=<value>" from a log file

Tags: regex, perl

Hi I have a requirement where I need to pull text of the form -  =  from a large log file.

log file consists of data like this:

```
[accountNumber=0, email=tom.cruise@gmail.com, firstName=Tom, lastName= , message=Hello How are you doing today ?
```

The output I expect is:

```
accountNumber=0
email=tom.cruise@gmail.com
firstName=Tom
```

etc.

Can anyone please help ? Also please explain the solution so that I can extend it to cater to my similar needs.

Comment: Are there `,` or `=` in any of the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a one-liner for this:

```
perl -nle 's/^\[//; for (split(/,/)){s/(?:^\s+|\s+$)//g; print}' input.txt
```

I also made another line of input to test with:

```
Matt@MattPC ~/perl/testing/13
$ cat input.txt
[accountNumber=0, email=tom.cruise@gmail.com, firstName=Tom, lastName= , message=Hello How are you doing today ?
[accountNumber=2, email=john.smith@gmail.com, firstName=John, lastName= , message=What is up with you?
```

Here is the output:

```
Matt@MattPC ~/perl/testing/13
$ perl -nle 's/^\[//; for (split(/,/)){s/(?:^\s+|\s+$)//g; print}' input.txt
accountNumber=0
email=tom.cruise@gmail.com
firstName=Tom
lastName=
message=Hello How are you doing today ?
accountNumber=2
email=john.smith@gmail.com
firstName=John
lastName=
message=What is up with you?
```

### Explanation:

**Expanded code:**

```
perl -nle '
           s/^\[//;
           for (split(/,/)){
                s/(?:^\s+|\s+$)//g;
                print
           }'
input.txt
```

**Line by line explanation:**

`perl -nle` calls `perl` with the command line options `-n`, `-l`, and `-e`. The `-n` adds a `while` loop around the program like this:

```
 LINE:
while (<>) {
... # your program goes here
}
```

The `-l` adds a newline at the end of every `print`. And the `-e` specifies my code which will be in single quotes (`'`).

`s/^\[//;` removes the first `[` if there is one. This searches and replaces on `$_` which is equal to the line.

`for (split(/,/)){` begins the `for` loop which will loop through the array returned by `split(/,/)`. The split will split `$_` since it was called with just one argument, and it will split on `,`. `$_` was equal to the line, but inside the `for` loop, `$_` still get set to the element of the array we are on.

`s/(?:^\s+|\s+$)//g;` this line removes leading and trailing white space.

`print` will print `$_` followed by a newline, which is our `string=value`.

`}'` close the `for` loop and finish the `'`.

`input.txt` provide input to the program.

Comment: it would be better if you explain your code little bit.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, I added an explanation. I wrote it pretty quickly since I gotta get to sleep now, but let me know if part of it needs additional clarification and I will add it tomorrow.

Comment: and +1 for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Going off your specific data and desired output, you could try the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'file.txt' or die "Can't open file $!";
my $data = do { local $/; <$fh> };

my @matches = $data =~ /(\w+=\S+),/g;

print join "\n", @matches;
```

[**Working Demo**](https://eval.in/173114)

Comment: This wouldn't capture his message at the end right? Because it has spaces in it.

Comment: Right, I think the asker wants all of it. That's why Sri put "etc" in his question. But I guess it is up to the asker.

Comment: If OP needs the other key-values then OP should phrase the question better, I am going off OPs expected output.

Answer (score 0):

**Perl One-Liner**

Use this:

```
perl -0777 -ne 'while(m/[^ ,=]+=[^,]*/g){print "$&\n";}' yourfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each line of the log ends with a closing square bracket, you can use this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $line = '[accountNumber=0, email=tom.cruise@gmail.com, firstName=Tom, lastName= , message=Hello How are you doing today ?]';

while($line =~ /([^][,\s][^],]*?)\s*[],]/g) {
    print $1 . "\n";
}
```